# PL/SQL Order of procedures

Tags: plsql, procedure

I'm new to PL/SQL.  This may be a dumb question, but does the order of the procedures in the DECLARE block have any impact on the order of the procedures in the BEGIN block?

Comment: Could you post an example of what you mean? Because, **usually** there are no procedures in DECLARE section. In executable part of a PL/SQL procedure (that's what you call the "BEGIN block", I presume), procedures are called in no particular order. Therefore, I'd put my bet to "no, there's no impact", but - you'd rather explain what you meant.

Comment: It does not. What impact are you seeing or concerned about?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is No. The the order in the declare block does not have any impact on begin block.